# Discord.Net - Sending command and then getting response

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have been struggling to find an answer to this question. I would like to get the response to a command and use that as a parameter - argument.

Example:

User: /say

Bot: What would you like me to say?

User: Hello, how is your day going?

Bot: Hello, how is your day going?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Discord.Addons.Interactive](https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive)

[Example code](https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive/blob/master/SampleApp/Modules/SampleModule.cs#L22-L31)