# Discord.NET C# How do I make the bot wait for an input before proceeding with the command

Tags: discord, discord.net

I was wondering how I could do something like this in my commands class:

```
  public string yuh;
  [Command("test")]
    public async Task test(params string[] args) 
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            await ReplyAsync("Tell me something.");
            ***WAIT FOR A USER INPUT***
            yuh = Context.Message.Content;

        }
        await ReplyAsync(yuh);
    }
```

What do I put in the ***WAIT FOR A USER INPUT***?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50054535/11159372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Discord.Addons.Interactive](https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive). It's a "Addon" for Discord.Net installed with NuGet.

```cs
var response = await NextMessageAsync();
```

[GitHub File Example](https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive/blob/master/SampleApp/Modules/SampleModule.cs#L22-L31)

Comment: I can't find Discord.Addons.Interactive in the list of NuGet Packages in the NuGet Package manager. How do I install this directly?

Comment: nvm found it! Thank you!